# How to Split Code into multiple controllers under single module in angular js?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, angular-controller

**Here I want to implement the concept of partial classes in c# for to split code among multiple physical files.**

I tried as below but it wont works for me.

```
<div ng-app="appmods" ng-controller="parentctrl">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />    
    {{name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="age" />
    {{age}}
    <input type="button" ng-click="showlog()" value="save" />
 </div>
```

Js.File

```
var appmod = angular.module('appmods',[]);

appmod.controller('firstctrl',function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.name = "phani";
    // code
    console.log($scope)


    return vm;

})


appmod.controller('ChildCtrl',function( $scope,$controller) {
    var vm = $controller('firstctrl', {
        $scope: $scope,
        options: {}
    });

    // extend view model
    vm.name = '';
    vm.age = 12;
    vm.showlog = function () {
        console.log('hello');
        console.log($scope);
    }
    return vm
})
```

Comment: In angular you can use `service` or `factory`. You can google it first. There are lots of examples out there. Basically they are designed to exchange the data in between controllers.

Comment: Here scenario is different,I have a code of 3000 lines in a controller.Due to new requirements i have to add code to the original controller itself. instead of that there is any possibility to write code in another file?